# Mac thinks USB is the wrong format

Tags: disk-utility, usb, partition, fat32

I have a USB drive that I cleaned and formatted as FAT32 on my Linux machine because `Diskutil disableOwnership` wouldn't work.  I plugged it into the Windows machine with the files I need and copied them onto the USB with no problems.  But when I plugged the USB into my Mac, it gave the error, "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer."

I reopened terminal and ran `diskutil info`.  Here's the output for the particular disk:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *30.8 GB    disk2
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         4.1 KB     disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS                         2.4 MB     disk2s2
```

Windows and Linux are both recognizing the disk correctly as a FAT32, but MacOS thinks it is an Apple Partition scheme.  What is a possible cause?  Is there a way to force MacOS to recognize the disk correctly?

Note: The reason I formatted the disk with Linux was that I get the error "Couldn't modify the partition map" when I use Diskutil to erase the disk.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362978/ehd-has-5-tb-capacity-but-finder-only-shows-600-gb) has a comment that FAT32 is not best for Mac. Can you format disc as ExFAT? That would be best if you want this to be cross-platform or HFS+ for Mac only. Reformatting a drive will delete all data on the drive.